# GWT SuggestBox: add multiple ClickHandlers to each suggestion

Tags: gwt

Add multiple ClickHandlers to each suggestion. For example, for each suggestion I want to have 2 links 'exclude' and 'include' and add a handlers to each link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SuggestBox let's you provide your own SuggestionDisplay if you don't like the default one.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to include more details in the question (I would comment but cant until i get more rep).

What type of widget/widgets are you using?

If its a suggestbox then the answer Thomas Broyer supplied should work.

To do this create a new class and extend

```
SuggestBox.DefaultSuggestionDisplay
```

Comment: Because `DefaultSuggestionDisplay` uses a `Menu` widget, I don't think it's a good start to extend it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar implementation at my workplace. We have a custom suggestion display class which extends `SuggestBox.SuggestionDisplay`. It is a `PopupPanel` at heart, with a `VerticalPanel` that holds our custom `Suggestion`s. Those items have click handlers.

Answer (score 0):

The project [advanced suggest box](https://code.google.com/p/advanced-suggest-select-box/) handles this kind of needs: you can use the Table layout for example to have your buttons (see the demo)